# Script on child type no longer working since upgrading ElasticSearch from 1.3x to 2.3x

Tags: elasticsearch

The query below works on my ES 1.3.4 index, but doesn't on my ES 2.3.0 index, any idea why this has stopped working or how I can fix it?  My index has a parent child relationship between product and product_region.

The error it gives is:

```
No field found for [product_region.mask] in mapping with types [product]
```

Relevant part of the query is:

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "wildcard": {
                      "product_number": {
                        "value": "*999*"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "wildcard": {
                      "product_code": {
                        "value": "*999*"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "or": [
          {
            "has_child": {
              "type": "product_region",
              "query": {
                "constant_score": {
                  "filter": {
                    "and": [
                      {
                        "missing": {
                          "field": "ref_val1"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "script": {
                          "script": "(doc['product_region.mask'].value & 65535) > 0"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "or": [
                          {
```

Comment: ^^ Add the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out I needed to change "script": "(doc['product_region.mask'].value & 65535) > 0" to "script": "(doc['mask'].value & 65535) > 0"